# How to get a dynamic resource key name programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

My program loads at runtime XAML file with following declaration of WPF control. The XamlReader.Load(...) method is used.

```xml
<TextBlock Name="txMy" Text="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyTextFromRes}"/>
```

It works perfect and shows text from dynamic dictionary correctly.
Now I need to know NAME of KEY that resource dictionary at runtime because XAML file can be various. I need to play with related dictionary values.

**How can I get a string with name of resource key ("*MyTextFromRes*" in this sample) at runtime in c# code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following helper method:

```
public string GetDynamicResourceKey(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    var value = dObj.ReadLocalValue(dp);
    var converter = new ResourceReferenceExpressionConverter();
    var dynamicResource = converter.ConvertTo(value, typeof(MarkupExtension)) as DynamicResourceExtension;
    return dynamicResource?.ResourceKey as string;
}
```

Now, use it with your `TextBlock`:

```
var resourceKey = GetDynamicResourceKey(txMy, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

I adapted this solution from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8c29768-54eb-452d-97af-8737e4e0477f/getresourcereference-or-smth-similar?forum=wpf).

Comment: Thank you but I need other. I want to get Key of resource that assigned to property. Also I glad to get string with whole expression "{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyTextFromRes}"

Comment: @user3774699 You should edit your question to make it clear what you want. Do you need to assign the resource in XAML? You can assign it programmatically, so you would know which key you assigned to a property.

Comment: XAML file is loaded dynamically at run-time. XamlReader loads XAML correctly and all declared controls works good.At runtime I see TextBlock instance with name "txMy". Its property txMy.Text shows value from related dictionary. Now I need to know KEY NAME that declared in Text property. OK I will try to edit question.