How to get the static resource key from a control?
Wpf control can use the pre-defined resource in runtime. Is it able to get the static resource key from a control? And how?
Thanks!
<Window
    x:Class="GetResourceKeyWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="MyName">Will</system:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Loaded="MyNameTb_Loaded" Text="{StaticResource MyName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

using System.Windows;

namespace GetResourceKeyWpf;

public sealed partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyNameTb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Is it able to the static resource key "MyName" for text property?
    } 
}

I searched my question in SO, and got a similar question for get the key for dynamic resource.
How to get a dynamic resource key name programmatically?
I tried it for static resource but ReadLocalValue just returned the string value "Will" which is not my target.
PS:
My expected result is to get the string "MyName", not the content "Will".
Then, I can do some job like TextBlock.ToolTips = resourceKey, to display the key when my app is running in debug mode for checking if someone choosed the wrong resource.

Why would you need that?

I am trying to display the resource key when my app is under debug mode. It will help to check if I choose the wrong resource.

"if someone chose the wrong resource" does not make sense to me. Who is someone except you? How to choose a resource? And how to choose a wrong one? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

@Clemens I am writing some custom controls for my team, other devs would will use these controls in their WPF projects. Finally the operator will run the WPF projects on machine, if the operator find the control display abnormal, the operator can take a picture to let the dev know what's the resource key quickly. Does it make sense? Let's focus on how to retrieve the resource key, plz.

"Does it make sense?" - not at all. Controls do not expose resources.

There is obviously no direct way to find out which resource key has been used to get a resource from a dictionary. The only things you can do is to iterate over the dictionary and compare values against your target value. Then get the key of a matching value. That does however not prove that the resource was used at all to generate the target value.

I don't understander why you call this code as a expose resource? textBlock.ToolTips = resourceKeyString;

@Clemens It is because I saw someone get the dynamic resource key from the control, stackoverflow.com/a/54269885/6231009. So I am wondering if I can do the same thing for static resource.

<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MyName}" Tooltip="MyName"/> - what else?

@Clemens Not good if you have tons of controls to modify.

Logically, the StaticResource Markup Extension is equivalent to the FindResource method.
object myName = FindResource("MyName"); // return "Will"

If a certain hierarchy of resources is possible and you need to get a value from a certain level of the hierarchy, then you need to execute a method from an element from this level of the hierarchy.
    <Window.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="MyName">Will</system:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <system:String x:Key="MyName">Will-StackPanel</system:String>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbl" Loaded="MyNameTb_Loaded" Text="{StaticResource MyName}" />
    </StackPanel>

object myName = tbl.FindResource("MyName"); // return "Will-StackPanel"


but ReadLocalValue just returned the string value "Will" which is not my target

This is what I didn't understand at all in your question.
The resource with the key "MyName " is the string "Will".
But this doesn't suit you.
And what result did you want to get? Please explain in more detail.
Perhaps you are interested in checking if a key is in a dictionary?
bool isContains = Resources.Contains("items");

Or you can get all the keys from the dictionary:
System.Collections.ICollection keys = Resources.Keys;

To search for a key hierarchically, you can create an extension method and use it:
    public static partial class FrameworkElementHelper
    {
        public static bool FindResourceKey(this FrameworkElement? element, object key)
        {
            while (element is not null)
            {
                if (element.Resources.Contains(key))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

bool isFindKey = tbl.FindResourceKey("MyName"); // Return true

Perhaps you need to get the value of a key from the element property to which it is set using StaticResource?
If so, then it is not possible to do so.
DinamicResource creates an Expression and assigns it to a DependencyProperty. That is why DinamicResource can ONLY be used with DependencyProperty.
Unlike it, StaticResource returns the desired value, so it can be used with ANY property. And as a result, it is impossible to find out from the received value by which key it was obtained.
Specifically for your task, you can replace StaticResource with DynamicResource. But in general, this will not always be possible.
I would also advise you to change the approach to implementing the task. If you want to check the settings of its child elements from the control logic, it is better to use CustomControl with mandatory template elements.

My expected result is to get the string "MyName", not the content "Will". Then, I can do some job like TextBlock.ToolTips = resourceKey, to display the key when my app is running in debug mode for checking if someone choosed the wrong resource.

@user6231009
I have added more options to my answer. Please take a look at them.

My question is quite similar to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269885/6231009 , but what I am looking for is the static resource key.

@user6231009
I have supplemented my answer once again.

Yes, I just take the textblock for example. I am writing some cumstom controls for my team. , I would like to display "MyName" on the tooltips of MyLabel when debug mode is on. There is tons of MyLable used in the projects. So for convenient, I would like to retrieval the static resource key name back inside the customer control code, then set the tooltips depends on debug condition.

@user6231009
For StaticResource this will not be possible. Only if you parse XAML, but that's a very difficult task.

Thanks, I will wait if someone can give other advice.

@user6231009
What don't you like about using DynamicResource?

Static resource can help designer get input hints when editing in VS. Additionaly, I heard that static resource seems to have a little better performance than dynamic resource. If there is really no way to get the key of static resource in the end, I will consider using dynamic resource.

@user6231009
"Better performance" is true. But compared to the overall cost of the WPF logic, it's like "Get one dollar off Mercedes buy."

You can replace StaticResource with your own markup extension that will store the key in some collection at the NameScope level and from which you can then retrieve it in Code Behind. But this will require design developers to use your custom markup extension instead of StaticResource.

Thanks for the advice! I will try it tomorrow.
